# Complex line bundles with connection can be parametrized by unitary character of fundamental group

Tags: mathematical-physics, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, k-theory, topological-k-theory

Recently I'm reading the book [Geometric Quantization and Quantum Mechanics](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387904696) and it states in chapter $3$ that

> Assume $(X,\omega )$ is a symplectic manifold, $(L,\alpha )$ is a complex line bundle over $X$ with $\alpha $ the corresponding connection form on $L$ satisfying $d\alpha =-\pi^{\ast }\omega $, then the set of equivalence classes of such line bundles with connection can be parametrized by the unitary characters of the group $\pi_1 (X)$.

I just don't know why and where are references. Do anyone know about this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be directly proved.

First notice that the one-dimensional unitary representation of $\pi_{1}(X)$ can be noted by $\text{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X),S^{1})$. Notice that $\text{Hom}(\pi_{1}(X),S^{1})=\text{Hom}(H_{1}(X;\mathbb{Z}),S^{1})=H^{1}(X;S^{1})$ via abelianization and the fact that $\text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}}(H_{0}(X),S^{1})=0$.
On the other hand, the complex line bundle on the symplectic manifold $X$ is determined by $H^{2}(X;\mathbb{Z})$. And also we have the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^{1}\rightarrow0$ and then we can obtain a long exact sequence $$\cdots\rightarrow H^{1}(X;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^{1}(X;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^{1}(X;S^{1})\rightarrow^{f} H^{2}(X;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\cdots$$
Then we only need to show that for the equivalence of the line bundle $(L,\alpha)$ is uniquely determined by $H^{2}(X;\mathbb{Z})$. This is obvious since for $[\gamma]\in\text{Ker}(f)=\text{Im}(H^{1}(X;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H^{1}(X;S^{1}))$, and the fact that $\alpha$ is equivalent to $\alpha+Z_{1}(L)$ and modulo the exact form we obtain that fix the line bundle $L$ the equivalence class of the connection form with the condition given above is determined by $H^{1}(L;\mathbb{R})$ and since the fiber of the vector bundle is contractible we have $H^{1}(L;\mathbb{R})=H^{1}(X;\mathbb{R})$. And then we can see that the equivalence class of the line bundle $(L,\alpha)$ can be parametrized by $H^{1}(X;S^{1})$, i.e. the unitary characters of $\pi_{1}(X)$.

Comment: I don't think it is uniquely determined by $H^2 (X;\mathbb{Z} )$ since the line bundle is already classified by $H^2 (X;\mathbb{Z} )$, so you mean that the connection on the line bundle is unique?

Comment: @TheWildCat Yes, that is what I mean since the connection satisfying the condition $d\alpha=-\pi^{*}\omega$ is determined by $H^{1}(L;\mathbb{R})=H^{1}(X;\mathbb{R})$ modulo the exact 1-form.

Comment: don't quite understand. $\alpha $ is not necessarily closed.

Comment: @TheWildCat Maybe I should explain it more precisely. Given a line bundle $L$ on the symplectic manifold $(X,\omega)$, and suppose that there exist two connection form $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $d\alpha=d\beta=-\pi^{*}\omega$, then we can see that $d(\alpha-\beta)=0$ which means that $(\alpha-\beta)\in Z^{1}(L)$, so $\alpha$ is unique modulo $Z^{1}(L)$ or more concretely $\alpha$ is unique modulo $H^{1}_{dR}(L)=H^{1}(L;\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: So you mean that the connection form is determined modulo $H^1 (L;\mathbb{R} )$ when the line bundle $L$ is fixed?

Comment: @TheWildCat Yes, that's what I mean.